# How to get reputation on here?

Tags: discussion

I can't do a lot of things on here because I don't have a **reputation**. How do I get a reputation?

Answer (score 5):

You get reputation<sup>1</sup> for **positive contributions** to the site.

The most obvious way would be asking **good questions** and writing **good answers** - when other users consider your post helpful, they will upvote them.

Other contributions are also rewarded with reputation, e.g. suggesting good and helpful edits of existing posts. The details of how to gain and lose reputation can be found [here](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) in our Help Center.

—————-

<sup>1</sup> Please note that “reputation”’on SE sites is a numeric value that reflects the quality of the posts etc. It’s part of the [gamification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamification) mechanism on Stack Exchange. So while you want to work on gaining reputation (= points via upvotes etc.) you want to be careful how you behave as a member of the community lest you end up [having *a* reputation](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/de/worterbuch/englisch/have-a-reputation).